# R: sort a matrix so that high values ​lie along the main diagonal

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, data.table

I have a squared matrix in a data frame and need to swap rows and columns so that the highes values are on the main diagonale and get smaller outwards.
I have trouble coding that because i'm new to coding.

A example matrix I got:

```
input <- data.table(
  c( 4, 4, 3, 5, 2),
  c( 4, 2, 5, 3, 4),
  c( 3, 5, 2, 4, 1),
  c( 3, 1, 4, 2, 5),
  c( 5, 3, 4, 4, 3)
)

output <- function(input)
output  #would be nice if the output could also be a data frame

5  4  3  2  1
4  5  4  3  2
3  4  5  4  3
2  3  4  5  4
1  2  3  4  5

I would appreciate help very much :)
```

Comment: So what have you attempted so far? Where is your code that does not work? Please provide a [mre] so that we can help fix your problem. I'd suggest reading [ask] and also have a look at [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/12672179). So please help us help you by [edit]ing the question and adding the details we need to help you.

Comment: Is the result always a full banded matrix? Why do you want a data.frame as result and not a more appropriate data structure?

Comment: what if you threw in like a 20 in the second row fifth column? Will that go to the fifth column/row after sorting or will it  go to the 2nd column/row? And will the resulting matrix be always symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure exactly how this should be done, but the following does the job:

```
toeplitz(sort(unique(unlist(input)), dec = TRUE))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    4    3    2    1
[2,]    4    5    4    3    2
[3,]    3    4    5    4    3
[4,]    2    3    4    5    4
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
```